# Need some help to build Programming Contest Judge System

Tags: operating-system

I have a plan to create a Onsite Programming Contest Judge  like PC^2, Domjudge.

I want to build the judge system web based (localhost) rather than desktop application.

Here is my objectives:

1. Judge system should be cross platform like PC2 [ which runs with JRE ]
2. Using Ruby, Python , PHP or Node.JS

Now the problem is to make the system cross platform which language is preferable most ?

Can Ruby, Python, PHP or Node.JS handle system command ? [eg. Compiling a C++/Java source code ,and running programs ] How they can handle the time limit of a process ?

Can anyone give me some helpful links ?
i have googled a lot, but didn't found anything about cross platform system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planing a web based Programming Contest Judge system, it will be cross platform since it is on the web, at least from the user point of view. But if you mean cross platform from the server point of view, you will need a cross-platform process management library, for example:

**Boost Process** (www.highscore.de/boost/process/)

**PoCo** (pocoproject.org/) (Processes namespace, in Foundation)

**Psutil** (code.google.com/p/psutil/) (for Python) if you choose python I recommend [Web.py](http://webpy.org/) as web framework

**Qt** (qt-project.org/) you could use Qt which implements many OS utilities in a platform-independent way, eg. processes, threads, networking, GUI...

**wxWidgets** also contains a cross-platform process control library for spawning child processes through the wxProcess class.

.... and should be much more libraries out there...

With **Node.js** you can create **child process** but I'm not sure how far you can go with it, for example I don't know if you can go on limiting the memory of a process.

But if for any reason you decide to develop the software for a specific platform, like **GNU/Linux**, you can start by understanding how the process management works for that specific platform ([**Linux (POXIS)**](http://siber.cankaya.edu.tr/ozdogan/SystemsProgramming/ceng425/ceng425.html), **Windows (Win32 API)**)